# Can Oracle SQL with WHERE and ORDER BY be sped up with an index based on filter and sort columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, indexing, explain

This query is quicker without the "order by":

```
select * from mytable where 1=1 
and internalid in ('abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno','pqr','stu') 
order by name, mytableid;
```

(In real life there are 999 strings in the IN clause).

If I run it through explain plan in Oracle it is using the unique index for "internalid".  There are no suggestions for improvement.

If I create a new nonunique index for "internalid, name, mytableid" it still uses the unique index above.  Am I doing the right thing?  Can I speed it up with an index for the sort columns?

(N.B. The "1=1" comes from the way we build SQL queries in our application - parameters can be applied dynamically with an AND without having to work out if it's the first one.)

Comment: Is it actually running slow? There's only a handful of rows to sort if internalid is unique, that's not going to take noticeable time.

Comment: That index wouldn't help for sorting anyway. Might save a block read or two but...

Comment: Ordering will have some overhead, but often an insignificant amount compared to the data retrieval. Is the unordered version actually quicker even if you run both versions repeatedly - or did you just run the ordered one first, so the unordered one then saw cached data which it could access faster? And are you measuring the time to retrieve all rows, or just the first chunk (e.g. first 50 rows by default in SQL Developer gird view)?

Comment: @Mat in real life there are 999 strings in the IN clause.  Still too few to matter?

Comment: @AlexPoole comparative timings were based on an AWR report by the hosting company.  With ORDER BY it was 25% slower.

Comment: @hobbes_child Often queries run faster the second time, purely due to caching, so it's important to know whether you tested both versions more than once. Otherwise you might run query A then query B, notice that B is faster, and conclude incorrectly that B is written more efficiently.